# Mod Rewrite on get vars

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a private project, which is basicly a profile system.
Now I've been trying how to improve the URL formatting.

At this moment, I am using URL's which look like:

-> http://example.com/overview
-> http://example.com/profile/?name=foo
-> http://example.com/jobs/?name=foo

Both overview and profile are directories on my website, which contain a single index.php file, which holds the PageID of which should be retrieved from the database.

Now, my goal is to format the URL to something as:

-> http://example.com/foo OR http://example.com/profile/foo 
-> http://example.com/foo/jobs OR http://example.com/profile/foo/jobs

Is there anyway to do this with MOD_REWRITE?

This would mean the original url would look something like http://example.com/?character=foo/jobs which is http://example.com/get_var/directory.

I've done my research on Stackoverflow and Google, searching for '*mod_rewrite get variables*'. But nothing seemed to be what I'd like to see happening.

Yours Sincerely,
Larssy1

Comment: So what URL does the end user see, and what URL does your server ultimately handle?

Comment: The user sees: http://mysite.com/profile/Foo/jobs ,, The server handles: http://mysite.com/profile/jobs/?character=Foo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract a portion of the URI between slashes and append it as a URL parameter, use the expression `([^/]+)` to capture all characters up to but not including the next `/` into `$1`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/([^/]+/?)?$ profile/$2?character=$1 [L]
```

The above rule will dynamically capture what follows `Foo` from your example, meaning that whether it was followed by `/jobs` or `/other` or `/somethingelse`, it would be appended as `/profile/somethingelse?character=Foo`.  If that isn't necessary, and `/jobs` is static, you don't need to capture it into `$2`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Don't dynamically capture what comes after the first variable group...
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)/jobs$ profile/jobs?character=$1 [L]
```

Comment: If I have 50pages functionating like this, does this mean I have to add a RewriteRule for every single page?

Comment: @larssy1 No, how do they differ? The top rule would address any value in place of `/jobs`.  If `/profile` changes, then that can be addressed too, but I would need examples.

Comment: A few examples would be: */profile/Foo/jobs, */profile/Foo/about, */profile/Foo, */profile/Foo/preferences. There is btw one flaw in your code, it saying */profile/Foo/jobs and */profile/Foo/jobs/ are different URL's, how to make the last / optional?

Comment: @larssy1 The first rule addresses all of those.  I added a `?` after the second capture group to address` /profile/Foo` with nothing following, but all the others would have worked as is.

Comment: Alright, so I now have the following code:
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /profile/$2/?character=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]*)$ /profile/?character=$1 [L] The only problem is that it is sensitive for when the URL ends with a / or not.. how to solve this?

Comment: @larssy1 Add `/?` onto the second group as I have added above.

Comment: Thanks, had to edit the code you gave since it was actually showing the destination URL in the browser, now it doesn't :)